# Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '_?'

Tags: swift, arguments, amazon-cognito

I am implementing a function to retrieve IdentityID and token of a custom identity provider as part of my work to setup authentication in Amazon Cognito. I need to add the token as part of my return statement, but in my return statement, I am getting an error.
**"Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '_?'".**

I do not understand what _? argument is exactly and how to conform to it.

```
import AWSCore
/*
 * Use the token method to communicate with your backend to get an
 * identityId and token.
 */
class DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider : AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper {
    override func token() -> AWSTask<NSString> {
    //Write code to call your backend:
    //pass username/password to backend or some sort of token to authenticate user, if successful, 
    //from backend call getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity with logins map containing "your.provider.name":"enduser.username"
    //return the identity id and token to client
    //You can use AWSTaskCompletionSource to do this asynchronously

    // Set the identity id and return the token
    self.identityId = resultFromAbove.identityId
    return AWSTask(result: resultFromAbove.token)
}
```

resultFromAbove.token is String?. and so when i use it, i get the error. However, if i just type in a string such as

```
return AWSTask(result: "abcd")
```

This seems to be fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

> return AWSTask(result: resultFromAbove.token)

to

> return AWSTask(result: resultFromAbove.token as NSString?)

Comment: I get the following error. **'String?' is not convertible to 'NSString'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?**. as! or as? works. If i do as NSString?, that also works, so whats the best approach here? A few additional questions. Are we casting to NSString because AWSTask is expecting NSString?. Do you know, in my original error, what does argument type '_?' mean?

Comment: @Sherry corrected the answer, the best approach, in my opinion, is  NSString? thus in case, the result is nil you will *return AWSTask(result: nil)* not throw an error. I don't know what argument type '_?'  means, sorry.